# Custom redirect with regex?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the following URL structure:

```
/vehicle_details.php?veh_id=918
```

To:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/my/url
```

I need it do it when `veh_id` is anything, so it redirects them all.

Comment: Could you just redirect /vehicle_details.php regardless of query string? If not, maybe you need RedirectMatch - http://superuser.com/questions/155139/htaccess-301-redirect-with-regular-expressions

Comment: Would you like to pass the veh_id to your new url?

Comment: Is `/my/url` is literal text or some dynamic string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+vehicle_details\.php\?veh_id=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.co.uk/my/url? [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @naomi for the idea.

As `vehicle_details.php` is a really old file that will be deleted, I simple created a new one with:

```
<?php 
    // old website redirects
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/my/url/");
    exit;
?>
```